# Connecting Amazon S3 via Datastage 11.5

Tags: datastage

I am trying to connect to Amazon S3 via DataStage 11.5 to fetch a list of files but the connection keeps getting timed out.
I have provided the Access key, Secret key and the bucket details. There is no other option in the stage to increase the timeout period or anything.

Has anyone tried this before and any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, then run aws command from Engine tier to verify if you are able to connect to AWS bucket... Check with your AWS folks how to get aws command running from Engine tier command line.

Check with your S3 team if it is a SSL enabled connection.

Try running job with $CC_MSG_LEVEL=2 to make AmazonS3 Connector to generate debug messages in job log.